# Auto-Correct Spelling Errors Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spell-checking

I'm trying to build a Rails application that auto-corrects the spelling of a Rails form after it submits. I realize that the auto-correcting won't be 100%, but I'm wondering if their are any good Ruby gems that I can use to do something like this.

So basically someone enters a few sentences into a text area, presses submit, the controller goes in takes the text and corrects any obvious spelling errors and then saves the "supposedly" error-free text to the database.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should not do this unless you ask the user if they want their content to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might try this:

```
gem install spellingbee
```